# cannot access local variable 'form' where it is not associated with a value error

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I am writing this django website and only today did this error start to come up in one of the views.
Here is the view in word:

```
def new_ingredient(request, recipe_id):
    """ "Add a new entry for a particular recipe"""
    recipe = Recipe.objects.get(id=recipe_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        # POST data submitted; process data
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_ingredient = form.save(commit=False)
            new_ingredient.owner = recipe
            new_ingredient.save()
            return redirect("recipe_book:recipe", recipe_id=recipe_id)

    # Display a blank or invalid form
    context = {"recipe": recipe, "form": form}
    return render(request, "recipe_book/new_ingredient.xhtml", context)
```

This is my model:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    time_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ingredients"

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.text[:50]}..."
```

This is my form:

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ["text"]
        labels = {"text": ""}
        widgets = {"text": forms.Textarea(attrs={"cols": 8})}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
Ylli.

I have tried this code before and no errors occurred, but today it started to put this error up and I have no idea why it is happening. I wasn't expecting any error to come up in this view so it's a great shocker that it did.

Comment: Please post the full traceback message so we don't have to guess.  But guessing... you only assign a value to `form` in a `POST`. There are cases where `form` isn't assigned but you try to use it anyway. That will raise an error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to access the `new_ingredient` via another request type than `POST`. Because you missed to instantiate an empty form. Just create a form variable and return it via context:

```
...
# Display a blank or invalid form
form = EntryForm()
context = {"recipe": recipe, "form": form}
return render(request, "recipe_book/new_ingredient.xhtml", context)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it solved the problem but now when I submit the entry this error comes up:IntegrityError at /new_ingredient/16/
NOT NULL constraint failed: recipe_book_ingredient.recipe_id. I hope you can help me with this new problem because I am not sure of what to do!

Comment: Please accept the answer and open a new specific question for the new issue. But I expect that you miss to set a recipe when adding an ingredient. The field cannot be None/NULL according to your model.